# Close button on lightbox is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a light box on Request a Quote button. But when i click on close button it doesn't close the lightbox 
http://expedition2india.com/tour_packages.php?destination=&package=26&tab=include&page_id=#placeholder

```
    <div id="inline_content" style="display:none;">
<div class="trans"></div> 
<div class="popup">              
                <div class="head left"><a href="javascript:" class="bt close">CloseT</a> 
                <h2>Request a Quote</h2>
                <p>Fill out the form below to request a quote.</p>                
                </div>
                 <div id="preloader"><img src="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>images/preloader.gif" /></div>
                <form id="reg-form"  class="formular" method="post" action="">     
                    <table cellpadding="0" width="100%"  cellspacing="0" border="0" class="left" style="padding:20px;">                             
                         <tr><td style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', verdana; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold"><strong>Selected Tour:</strong> <span class="selected_tour"><?php echo $tour['package_name']; ?></span></td></tr>         

                         <!--<tr><td style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', verdana; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold"><strong>Selected Date:</strong> <span class="selected_date"></span></td></tr> -->

                        <tr><td><input type="text" name="cname" id="cname" class="textbox2bg validate[required,minSize[3],maxSize[50]] text-input" placeholder="Name" /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="textbox2bg validate[required,custom[email]] text-input" placeholder="Email Id" /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" class="validate[required,custom[phone]] text-input"/></td></tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><select name="travelMonth" id="travelMonth" class="textarea2bg validate[required] text-input">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Travel month</option>
                                    <option>January</option>
                                    <option>February</option>
                                    <option>March</option>
                                    <option>April</option>
                                    <option>May</option>
                                    <option>June</option>
                                    <option>July</option>
                                    <option>August</option>
                                    <option>September</option>
                                    <option>October</option>
                                    <option>November</option>
                                     <option>December</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><select name="adults" id="adults" class="textarea2bg validate[required] text-input">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select No. of Adults</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="10">11</option>
                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                                    <option value="13">13</option>
                                    <option value="14">14</option>
                                    <option value="15">15</option>
                                    <option value="16">16</option>
                                    <option value="17">17</option>
                                    <option value="18">18</option>
                                    <option value="19">19</option>
                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                    <option value="20+">20+</option>

                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><select name="child" id="child">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select No. of Children</option>
                                    <option value="0">0</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><select name="hotel_type" id="hotel_type" class="textarea2bg validate[required] text-input">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Hotel Types</option>
                                    <option value="first_class">First Class</option>
                                    <option value="deluxe">Deluxe</option>
                                    <option value="Oppulent">Oppulent</option>                                    
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                      
                        <tr>
                            <td><textarea name="otherinfo" id="otherinfo" placeholder="Other Information"></textarea><input type="hidden" name="selected_date" id="selected_date" /></td></tr>                   
                        <tr><td><input type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $tour['id']; ?>" name="tour" id="tour" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit" class="bt" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
                <div id="thanks"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Copy the relevant code here please

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to delete simply can hide or removed from DOM.

Tried this way

```
$("#Iwanttohide").hide()

$("#Iwanttohide").html("");
```

You can also tried [fadeout](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) to hide the elements with fade animation.

Comment: I have write jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('#inline_content').hide('500'); but it is not working

Comment: the display:none will be added into inline stylesheet. you can debug it in Firebug